# Header and page numbers with pdfpages

Tags: header-footer, pdf, pdfpages

I have a chapter of attachments which contains pdf files in this format, using the awesome pdfpages package:

```
\chapter{Title}
Lots of multipage pdfs following
\includepdf[pages=-,frame,scale=0.9]{abc.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,frame,scale=0.9]{def.pdf}
...
```

This works, but apparently clears out the header and page numbers of the parent document. What setting do I have to change to get back the header and page numbers?

Comment: As far as I understand ---and unfortunately--- this is not possible.  However, I do have a little hope because the table of contents points to the correct page when using multiple `\includepdf`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the `pagecommand` key to declare the desired page style for the included pages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Some centered header}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}}]{b}

\end{document}
```

The file b.tex used to produce `b.pdf` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

The resulting document, after the inclusion is (notice that the included pages have the `fancy` page style of the parent document):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What is the reason for the missing header and page numbers? If I understand your post correctly, I am generating a 'new header'. Can I ask Latex somehow to use the parent document format 'original header' rather than the fancyhdr?

Comment: what is the solution if `scrpage2` is used instead of `fancyhdr`

Comment: I got it! \includepdf[pages=-,frame,scale=0.85,pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{b.pdf} enforces the original header with page numbers. Without the scaling, the pdfs would overlap with the header. pagecommand={\pagestyle... got me on the right track.

Comment: @Gonzola, I suspect that pdfpages automatically sets the pagestyle to empty...?

Comment: @Hauke yes; the default for pagecommand is \pagestyle{empty}.

Comment: That's not correct. It is working because the `\pagestyle{fancy}` command in the preamble. If you remove that line it does not work. You have to write `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{b}`

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem which was easily solved by using `pagecommand` but without any additional style or package. Just this way :

```
\chapter{Title}
Lots of multipage pdfs following
\includepdf[pages=-,frame,scale=0.9,pagecommand={}]{abc.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,frame,scale=0.9,pagecommand={}]{def.pdf}
```

to force latex to use the current page style