# How to add page # of ## to an exam with a front page

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages

I am using the exam package as follows:

```
\documentclass[answers, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\begin{document}
%\includepdf{frontpage.pdf}
\begin{questions}
        
\question

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I have two problems.

- I tried to add page # of ## using the method described at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235/5283) but the packages needed seem to conflict. I get

> Command \lhead already defined.
> ...ef\f@nch@olh{#2}\f@nch@def\f@nch@elh{#1}}

- My second problem is that I want page 1 of ## to be on the front page.  The includepdf line should include the front page so it would need to be overwritten on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, the `exam` class already defines header and footer. That is why it clashes with `fancyhdr`. Also, it defines the command `\numpages` so you don't need the `lastpage` package.

Have a look at chapter 11 of the [examdoc](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epsh/exam/examdoc.pdf) for header and footer. Here I added the page # of ## as the right foot with `\rfoot{page \thepage{} of \numpages}`

To add this footer to your frontpage, have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117960/header-and-page-numbers-with-pdfpages/117975#117975). When you use `\includepdf`, add the optional argument `pagecommand={\pagestyle{headandfoot}}`. i used it with `headandfoot` style, but you could use others.

```
\documentclass[answers, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\footer{}
    {page \thepage{} of \numpages}
    {}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\pagestyle{headandfoot}}]{frontpage.pdf}
\begin{questions}
        
\question

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has both page # in the bottom middle and also page # of ## in the bottom right.  I would like to have only page # of ## and for that to be in the bottom middle.

Comment: I focused on adding page # of ## and I didn't clear the footer. I'll update my answer.